# How to find installed apps which are using SMS feature

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, sms, samsung, sms-blocking

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 Neo (Android KitKat). Some of the apps are using my SMS feature and SMS are costing pennies from my pocket without my knowledge.

I want to know what are all the apps which are sending SMS. If I found list of Apps, is this possible to restrict them from not using SMS feature without uninstalling them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Settings -> Apps -> Downloaded`. Here you'll see a list of all the apps that you have downloaded from the internet.

If you open any one and scroll down to the bottom, you'll see all the permissions that the app has. An app that sends messages on its own would have the `send SMS messages` permission enabled, which looks like this.

[image]

If you see this in an app, you have found the potential culprit.

---

Alternatively, you can download a third-party application like [App Permission Watcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.struse.apewatch&hl=en), to watch which app has the `send SMS messages` permission enabled.

---

Unfortunately, if you are not rooted, the only way you can stop the app from sending SMS messages is by uninstalling it.

However, if you are rooted, then you can edit the permissions of each app using your superuser controller.

Comment: Settings -- > General --> Application Manager for list of installed Apps.

Comment: @sunleo Thanks for pointing it out. I'm using CyanogenMod, so the settings are a little different from Touchwiz.

Answer (score 0):

To find all apps with a specific permission, there's a much easier way then checking them each manually: use a [Permission Checker](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions#group_379). I'd recommend taking a look at **[aSpotCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.aSpotCat)**, which is around for quite a while (I remember it even back from Eclair in 2011 :)

[image: aSpotCat] [image: aSpotCat] [[image: aSpotCat]]

*aSpotCat* allows you to browse your installed apps by permissions (and more, see first screenshot). Especially for your question is the second screenshot: see what apps can *send* SMS messages. To make it easier for you to find a permission, they are grouped (third screenshot).

---

Now, restricting access is a different thing. Multiple approaches can be thought of, but they are often either specific to an Android version (e.g. AppOps are only available with Android 4.3 and 4.4), require root, or need to manipulate and re-install the apps (thus often preventing updates, as modifications also change the app signature). As you're using Kitkat, the first group should fit your needs, and you can check for some [AppOps FrontEnds](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions#group_1027). If your device is rooted, you might also take a look at some [Stand-Alone Permission Manager](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions#group_1028). For further details on those, please also visit our sister-site for Software-Recommendations, and see: [Android permissions manager](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/21355/185).

Enjoy!