# Bluetooth keeps getting turned on

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 with Android 5.0 and since about 2 weeks or so my Bluetooth keeps getting turned on.

Until now I only used Bluetooth for connecting with my Bluetooth speakers.

I already tried: rebooting the phone and checking for viruses with Kaspersky Mobile.

Maybe there's an app that shows me all apps that have the permission to turn on Bluetooth so that I can deinstall those to see if that helps? Or any idea what the issue could be here?

Comment: Strictly speaking, asking explicitly for apps is off-topic here. But take a look at *aSpotCat* which does what you want – see [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/116382/16575) for details.

Comment: @Izzy: I wasn't asking explicitly for apps - however an app to check permissions could be helpful and/or the solution to my problem. Thanks for your recommendation - it worked well.

Comment: Glad to read! May I suggest to update your answer with details on how you found out?

Comment: Thanks for finding a previous question and for posting your answer on that question as well: it makes it much easier to keep the site tidy and helps future visitors to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to deinstall [FireChat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FireChat).